# An article about her at New York Times vs alternatives

Tags: prepositions

1. An article about her at New York Times
2. An article about her on New York Times
3. An article about her at newyorktimes.com
4. An article about her on newyorktimes.com

I suspect that the first and the fourth are correct, but I am not sure. [The research I did.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on) Is **on** more specific than **at**?

P.S. The article [in question](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/06/29/world/europe/italy-migrants-captain-arrest.html)

Comment: If you're talking about an article in the printed copy, it's "in the New York Times". When you're talking about a website, I don't think that usage has settled down yet between "at" and "on".

Comment: An online New York Times article about her. For this newspaper, you have to have the the.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what sounds natural:

- An article about her **in the** New York Times (for print newspapers)
- An article about her **in** Time [magazine] (for magazines, the "magazine" is optional)
- An article about her **on** newyorktimes.com (for websites)

Comment: Or an article about her **at** http://newyorktimes.com/section/date/title.html

Comment: Or on/at the New York Times website/web presence if you dislike the idea of showing the actual URL in your text.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ethan, Colin and Stuart about the usage. But **on** is not more specific than **at**. They are just different. There is often no strict rule about why one preposition gets used over another in English. You just have to learn each usage.